# Lottie UWP support

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, lottie

I was trying around with Lottie for Xamarin.Forms on iOS and UWP and now I am totally confused. Because my UWP App doesn't show the animations, i searched a little and found out, that UWP is not supported by Lottie. But because the Nuget is referencable from within my UWP App, I looked into the description of that Nuget and the Lottie Team wrote, that it is.

[image]

So what is now correct? And if UWP IS supported, are there additional steps needed to do?

Comment: Hope [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/ifdefWINDOWS/ifdef-LottieUWP?term=Lottie&lang-en=true) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be a "typo" in the nuget description, if you if look at the source code from martijn00, he bound the iOS and Android Lottie native libraries (not the web version)

There is a html/js version of Lottie (`lottie-web`) that you could use via a Xamarin.Forms' `WebView` on iOS, Android, UWP.

It is really easy to setup and you do not need any custom packages/add-ins. Just one JavaScript file (`lottie.js`), your json-based animation file, and some simple html.

re: https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web

## Example of using local files with `lottie-web`

Place your files in each of native app local resources, Assets (`AndroidAsset`) for Android, Resources for (`BundleResource`) iOS, etc...

```
├── lottie.html
├── lottie.js
└── lottieLogo.json
```

Note: These files should be pre-compressed/minimized maximum loading efficiency

Note: You can "link" them from a single source so you do not actually have multiple copies across the solution.

#### Lottie.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="width: 100%;height: 100%">
<head>
    <script id="animData" type="application/json">
        LottieJsonReplaceMe
    </script>
    <script>
        LottieJavaScriptReplaceMe
    </script>
</head>
    <body style="background-color:#ccc; margin: 0px;height: 100%;">
        <div style="width:100%;height:100%;background-color:#333;" id="lottie"></div>
        <script>
            var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('animData').innerHTML);
            console.log("start:");
            console.log(data);
            console.log("end:");
            var animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
              container: document.getElementById('lottie'),
              animationData: data,
              renderer: 'svg/canvas/html',
              loop: false,
              autoplay: true,
              name: "StackOverflow",
              });
            var anim = bodymovin.loadAnimation(animation);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### lottie.js

- https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web

#### lottieLogo.json

- Your Lottie json animation data file

Combining the html, javascript, and json into one string avoids the  XMLHttpRequest/CORS security on the various platforms/browsers when dealing with local files (`file://localhost/....`), otherwise each platform's embedded browser control settings have to be mod'd.

Note: Using `Xamarin.Essentials` from .NetStd/Forms library to obtain a stream to the platform dependent readonly app contents and for the cache location to save the combine html (for repeated usage efficiently).

```
    string html;
    var htmlCachedFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, "lottie.html");
#if DEBUG
    if (File.Exists(htmlCachedFile)) File.Delete(htmlCachedFile);
#endif
    if (!File.Exists(htmlCachedFile))
        using (var htmlStream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("lottie.html"))
        using (var jsStream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("lottie.js"))
        using (var jsonStream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("data.json"))
        {
            var jsonReader = new StreamReader(jsonStream);
            var json = jsonReader.ReadToEnd();
            var jsReader = new StreamReader(jsStream);
            var js = jsReader.ReadToEnd();
            var htmlReader = new StreamReader(htmlStream);
            var html1 = htmlReader.ReadToEnd();
            var html2 = html1.Replace("LottieJavaScriptReplaceMe", js);
            html = html2.Replace("LottieJsonReplaceMe", json);
            File.WriteAllText(htmlCachedFile, html);
        }
    else
        html = File.ReadAllText(htmlCachedFile);
    webView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource() { Html = html };
```

#### Lottie UWP Port

There is a Lottie port to C#/UWP, I have not used it personally, but it should be possible to add a custom Forms' renderer and integrate it into martijn00 Xamarin.Forms Lottie wrapper to add UWP support:

```
https://github.com/azchohfi/LottieUWP
```

Note: You might want to review the Github issues for this port as it appears not all animations are supported(?) and there are other outstanding issues...

Comment: Have you got some examples for this?

Comment: You add the html/js/json files to your native projects just like Xamarin WebView "loading local content" example walk you through: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#local-html-content

Comment: So after a LOT of try and error, I still cannot get it to work. I've added the `WebView` and set up as described, added a [Html](https://nopaste.xyz/?f6b28cdd2d5712d7#jTOj97nrjCMUFbXbULmInLF07mcRRhBNFpgQ+EJkmCc=) which seem to work cause I see the Background, but there is no Animation displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has officially supporting Lottie on Windows for UWP apps.

https://github.com/windows-toolkit/Lottie-Windows

However, certain features are not yet supported. You can check this table to see if the feature you are using is already supported in UWP: https://airbnb.io/lottie/supported-features.html