# Are Lottie animations supported in Xamarin.Forms UWP projects?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, lottie

I am trying to add Lottie animations to my project. 
So far I've only tested on android and I got it working.
Now I'm also trying to add them to my UWP app but I can't find a guide on how to do this.

There is [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/animations/lottie-scenarios/getting_started_json) that tells me lottie is supported on UWP.

And [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53308550/lottie-uwp-support) and (probably as a reaction) [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53412067/lottieuwp-embedded-into-xamarin-forms) suggests it is possible within xamarin forms uwp.

I can't find a clear reference (or a tutorial) online if this is supported for Xamarin.Forms UWP projects. I'm mainly in doubt because I'm not sure if the Xamarin.Forms.UWP 'flavor' is the same as a 'normal' UWP application.

I could really appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Lottie Animation through XF is not supported in my knowledge but it can be done natively in UWP!

Comment: @sjors I try to use Lottie in Xamarin.Uwp, but it can not display Lottie, so I think Lottie is an iOS, Android, and React Native library that renders the After Effects animations in real time. This features are not yet supported for Xamarin.forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it has something to do with [this bug](https://github.com/Baseflow/LottieXamarin/issues/255).

Although [this sample](https://github.com/DanielCauser/XamarinFFImageLoadingAndLottie) with an older version (2.5.4) was not built with "support" for UWP 
I did get it working by adding the resources to the root dir and setting the build action to Content.

Downgrading the library in my own project to 2.5.4 fixed the problem for me.